# passing in self data in python

Tags: python, instance-methods

Can you please clarify how it is that `self.add(x)` below works the same way as `self.data.append(x)`?
That is, how does `self.add(x)` know to append to the list because we have not explicitly stated `self.data.add(x)`?  When we state `y.addtwice('cat')`, `'cat'` is added to `'self'`, not `self.data`.

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=[]
    def add(self,x):
        self.data.append(x)
        return self.data
    def addtwice(self,x):
        self.add(x)
        self.add(x)
        return self.data

>>> y = Bag()
>>> y.add('dog')
['dog']
>>> y.addtwice('cat')
['dog', 'cat', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `addtwice` calls methods which are defined on self, and because self.data is a "mutable type", addtwice's call to add will end up appending the value of self.data. `add`, in turn calls self.data.append

When calling a function in a computer program, you can think of the process as being a series of substitutions like this:

```
# -> means (substitution for)
# <= means "return"
y = Bag()
y.add('dog') -> 
     y.data.append(x) ->
         #(machine code)
     <= y.data
# at this point, at the command propmt, python will just print what was returned.
y.addtwice('cat')->
     y.add('cat')->
         y.data.append(x) ->
             #(machine code) 
         <= y.data
     #nothing cares about this return
     y.add('cat')->
         y.data.append(x) ->
             #(machine code)
         <= y.data
     #nothing cares about this return either
     <= y.data
# at this point, at the command propmt, python will just print what was returned.
```

`self`, itself, is never really appended in any of those cases though. `self.data` is.

Comment: @Saher I've been thinking a lot about language design of late, and this is how McCarthy originally proposed Lisp (and how Alonzo Church proposed Lambda Calculus).

Comment: Thanks very much, @cwallenpoole, for a detailed and clear explanation. I really appreciate it. To me, the key was learning that "add, in turn calls self.data.append" as GWW also noted. That is, I did not know how self.add and self.data.append were related.

Answer (score 1):

`self.add(x)` calls the instance method `add` which in turn calls `self.data.append(x)`

Answer (score 1):

> When we state y.addtwice('cat'), 'cat' is added to 'self', not self.data

This is incorrect. `cat` is in fact added to `self.data`. Why would you think it was added to `self`?

`y.add('dog')` is the same as doing `Bag.add(y, 'dog')`. So `add` is really doing `y.data.append('dog')`, it's customary to use the name `self` instead.

`y.addtwice('cat')` is the same as doing `Bag.addtwice(y, 'cat')`. So `addtwice` is really doing `y.add('cat')` twice, which is the same as doing `Bag.add(y, 'cat')` twice. So `addtwice` is really doing `y.data.append('cat')` twice.

The `self` in each *instance method* is just an automatically added variable pointing to the *instance* it's called on, in this case `y`.

Comment: Thanks @agf for your reply. Yes, I said it incorrectly on purpose because that is what it seemed like it was doing. Before I got a reply to my question, I did not see why we could just say self.add(x) and the input would still be added to self.data.   I would have thought we had to state self.data.append(x) for all the cases to be added to the list. That was why I asked for clarification.

Comment: Yep, that's why I explained it.

Answer (score 1):

Let look at function `add(self, x)` from class Bag.

When that function is called, one of the parameter is self, which is the object itself, in this case, the same instance of `Bag` whose `add` function is called.

Therefore, in function `add`, calling `self.data.append(x)` is basically calling function append on `data` list of `Bag`, thus, adding the element `x` into the list.

Same thing for function `addtwice`. By calling function `add` twice, two elements are added into `data` list of Bag.

Both functions return the `data` list.

Answer (score 1):

`add(self, x)` is just a function that you want to call.

`append` is a built in function that adds an element to the list.

so your add function basically uses append to add the element you want to the list and return the list you named `data`

`self.addtwice` will call self.add exactly two times and so will add the element twice.

Comment: Thank you, @Saher. You really helped to explain it for me by stating that "add(self, x) is just a function" and "append is a built in function". I got it. I got the difference.